# Need to alter the order of <div>'s when in mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When I alter the screen size to a phone view, `<div>`'s seem to stack in a different order. Is there a way to enforce divs to stack a particular order with media queries, I've tried to search everywhere and cannot find a simple way to do this. I am using [Foldy Grids](https://github.com/davatron5000/Foldy960) just to use for the responsiveness of them.

**Order of divs on a full screen is:**
1.)Image on left, text on right
2.)Text on left, image on right

**When it goes to a mobile view, I would like it to be stacked from top to bottom in order of:**

1.)Image

1.)Text

2.)Image

2.)Text

**At present, they order as:**

1.)Image

1.)Text

2.)Text

2.)Image

**html:**

```
<!-- First section -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid-2">
            <img src="images/EnrolYourself2Small.png">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-4">
             <h1 class="left-align fontAmaticH1">Text............</h1>
             <p class="left-align fontPlayfair">More text...........</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
<!-- Second section -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid-4">
            <h1 class="left-align fontAmaticH1">2nd text.........</h1>
            <p class="left-align fontPlayfair">more of 2nd div text........</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-2">
            <img src="images/MonitorProgressSmall.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this using some kind of framework? If not, please include the relevant CSS.

Comment: You should take a look at flexbox and restructure your HTML (e.g. remove `<br>` altogether).

Comment: @Sirko I'm just using Foldy Grids for a real quick responsiveness of the divs, but I didn't know if I could overwrite in CSS with something easy to stack them in a particular order.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 is flexbox something I can add in now, or this something that has to be done from beginning?

Comment: Flexbox is a browser feature and can therefore still be used at this time. You should combine it with media queries (also a browser feature). Both are CSS constructs.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at CSS media queries.

[this link might provide you a basis for what you want](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

For ordering your content, you can choose CSS grid:

[Link for the exmaples](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-template.asp)

And use grid-template on each query depending on the device you are displaying your content

Example:

```css
.main{
  display:grid;
  grid-template:
    'imagespace1'
    'textspace1'
    'imagespace2'
    'textspace2'
}

.image1{
  grid-area: imagespace1
}

.image2{
  grid-area:imagespace2
}

.text1{
  grid-area:textspace1
}

.text2{
  grid-area:textspace2
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="main"] {
    grid-template:
    'imagespace1'
    'imagespace2'
    'textspace1'
    'textspace2'
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='image1'>image1</div>
  <div class='image2'>image2</div>
  <div class='text1'>text1</div>
  <div class='text2'>text2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the comments?

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, i don't have nough rep to comment but i added an example, hope it's the answer.